# Etale over a product implies etale over factor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I will say an $R$-algebra, $A$, is finite étale over a commutative (with unity) ring $R$ if there exists some (faithfully-flat) $R$-algebra, $W$, such that $A\otimes_{R} W \cong W^{n}$ as a $W$-algebra. My question comes from Lenstra's notes on Galois Theory for Schemes.

**Question:** If $A$ is finite étale over $R^{n}$, the direct product of $n$-copies of $R$, then is $A$ finite étale over $R$ itself?

This question itself has, for me, come from trying to prove that a composition of finite étale algebras is again finite étale over the base; I have reduced to the question above, but I can't get any further!

Can anyone give me a hint as to how this could be shown? or indeed, if it is false, give me a counter example? Thank you very much!

**Edit:** I am confused about the change of base. If $W$ is the $R^{n}$-algebra over which $A$ splits, this means $A \otimes_{R^{n}} W \cong W^{m}$. To answer the question though I need to figure out an algebra which splits when tensored with $A$ over $R$ --- $A \otimes_{R} - \cong - ^{r}$

Comment: The category of $R^n$-algebras is $n$ copies of the category of $R$-algebras. Use that to decompose a faithfully flat $R^n$-algebra into $n$ faithfully flat $R$-algebras and then look at your definition carefully.

Comment: I see that we can decompose the algebra in this way, thank you. What is confusing me is the fact that one tensor product is over $R^{n}$, and the other is over $R$. Perhaps I should put this in my OP. 

If W is the $R^{n}$-algebra, then $A \otimes_{R^{n}} W = W^{n}$. However, I need to translate this into some $A\otimes_{R} - $, where the base ring is $R$ not $R^{n}$. It has got my seriously confused!